# Question about Update on Trigger with condition

Tags: mysql

I can't find the correct syntax for the trigger I tried to code.

I want to update a timestamp every time there is an update on the table but only for specific rows. I want to update the "UPDATE_TIME" only for the last "N_TACHE"

I can't find how to use SET with a where clause.

```
CREATE TRIGGER "time_on_update"
BEFORE UPDATE ON "SAVE_UPDATE"
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF
(NEW.DATE_DE_RDV <> OLD.DATE_DE_RDV)
OR
(NEW.ADRESSE <> OLD.ADRESSE)
OR
(NEW.CODE_POSTAL <> OLD.CODE_POSTAL)
OR
(NEW.VILLE <> OLD.VILLE)
THEN        
SET (NEW.UPDATE_TIME = current_timestamp WHERE N_TACHE= (SELECT MAX(N_TACHE));
END IF;
```

If you have any suggestion I take it.

Thanks in advance

EDIT :

This one is working but it update all the rows and I just want to update "update_time" for the last value of "N_TACHE" when "RDV","ADRESSE","CODE_POSTAL" or "VILLE" is updated

```
    DELIMITER $$
    CREATE TRIGGER `time_on_update`
    BEFORE UPDATE ON `SAVE_UPDATE`
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN

    IF
    (SELECT MAX(N_TACHE)
    FROM SAVE_UPDATE
    WHERE
    ((NEW.DATE_DE_RDV <> OLD.DATE_DE_RDV)
    OR
    (NEW.ADRESSE <> OLD.ADRESSE)
    OR
    (NEW.CODE_POSTAL <> OLD.CODE_POSTAL)
    OR
    (NEW.VILLE <> OLD.VILLE)))
    THEN        
    SET NEW.UPDATE_TIME = current_timestamp;
    END IF;
    END
    $$
    DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: You are going to have to expand on what n_tache is and where it comes from.

Comment: SET NEW.UPDATE_TIME = (SELECT current_timestamp FROM SAVE_UPDATE WHERE N_TACHE= (SELECT MAX(N_TACHE)) ;

Comment: I tried this but the syntax is wrong. I don't know how to deal with "SET" when I want to only update rows in certain condition

Comment: I tried to use CASE with "UPDATE 'table_name' but when I do this, I got this error message "could not run statement: Can't update table 'SAVE_UPDATE' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger"

Comment: SELECT N_TACHE
        FROM SAVE_UPDATE
        WHERE N_TACHE= (SELECT MAX(N_TACHE));
        IF
  (NEW.DATE_DE_RDV <> OLD.DATE_DE_RDV)
  OR
  (NEW.ADRESSE <> OLD.ADRESSE)
  OR
  (NEW.CODE_POSTAL <> OLD.CODE_POSTAL)
  OR
  (NEW.VILLE <> OLD.VILLE)
  THEN  
        SET NEW.UPDATE_TIME = current_timestamp;
        END IF;

Comment: With this code I got this error message

Comment: Error Code: 1415. Not allowed to return a result set from a trigger